# When a clawed beast attacks its prey, inflicting a deep wound in its flesh, what's the word used to describe this sort of attack?

Tags: single-word-requests

In Portuguese we have a specific word for that, [*cravar*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/cravar) (as in to nail or to affix with nails, from [Latin *clavare*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clavo#Latin)) but I don’t know if in English there's a single word that works like that. It’s about piercing or pinning the flesh with really sharp pointed claw, like how you’d nail a picture to the wall by driving a sharp pointed nail into the wall.

I first thought about *to carve*, but then I found out these are false friends (because [*carve* in English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/carve) is etymologically related to verbs for notching and probably even to engraving).

Someone also told me that the animal “drives its claws into” the prey’s flesh, and that makes sense, I’ve heard this before, but I’d like to know of more words that describe this action.

Comment: The usual term is *mauled*.

Comment: There is the verb "to claw" - The scratch or tear with the claws, however this tends to imply the motion of the claws through the skin/flesh. "The cat clawed my hand." "The dog clawed at the door but it would not open." For example, for describing a lion attacking an antelope, we would say, "The lion sank its claws into the antelope."

Comment: Which precise action? Is it specifically a word for making a single deep wound into flesh (like *stabbing* or even *impaling*), or is it a more general term for a savage attack with claws that a wild animal makes (*mauling*, as mentioned). "Drives its claws into" indicates getting a hold of someone in a cruel way, more than it indicates a savage attack likely to cause death.

Comment: @StuartF *Rem acu tetigisti!* as once upon a time you said to somebody who'd really nailed it.  Think more in that direction. :)

Comment: @tchrist Kudos for editing my question, it was a great improvement altogether, thanks.

Comment: @StuartF I am replying a bit late, but still I need to know this. It's for some lyrical verses I wrote, where I need to replace the word "carve" for something that actually has meaning in English, if possible, without compromising the metric.
In the sense used it is more like that added in the edited version: " like how you’d nail a picture to the wall by driving a sharp pointed nail into the wall."

Answer (score 2):

The word that comes to my mind is *maul*:

> *Maul* is both the name of a heavy hammer, and also a verb meaning beating and scratching. Tigers, lions, bears––animals with powerful paws and sharp claws, will maul their victims. —[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/maul)

One of the funnier examples of the word in action: [Friends: Ross Gets Mauled by Cat](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=u0kAO9rJB2o).

Comment: Being better educated than us moderns, Shakespeare in *Cymbeline* wrote “*...More sweet than our blest fields: his royal bird / Prunes the immortal wing, and [cloys](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/34773) his beak / As when his God is pleased”*, and ever since then folks have pondered what he really meant. If you [back up one entry](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/34772) you’ll likely see why he used it like that, taking the French cognate to the asker's Portuguese verb. Pity it’s obsolete:  nobody uses it in quite [that ***inclavating*** sense now](https://www.oed.com/view/th/class/210564).

Answer (score 1):

The verb **sink** can be used as in "to sink its claws". It can be better understood than the verb **claw** because *to claw* usually implies the motion of the claws through the skin/flesh as @Greybeard mentioned in the comments. *Claw* doesn't imply deep penetration or inflicting a deep wound.

*[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sink_1)* definition of the verb si*nk* and an example sentence:

> to push something sharp into something solid 
> *The cat sank its claws into my leg.*

*Sink* can be used both transitively and intransitively; and even figuratively.

*[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/180225?rskey=Lf9XZT&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid)* definitions of the verb *sink*:

> *intransitive.* Of a sharp weapon or object: to force a way into or through something, to penetrate. With into, through, or adverb complement. 
> *transitive.* To thrust or force (something sharp) into (also in) a solid object or body.

*[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/34017?rskey=lpqIl5&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)* definitions of the verb *claw*:

> *transitive.* To scratch or tear with the claws, or (transferred) with the nails or a pointed instrument. 
> To seize, grip, clutch, or pull with claws. 
> *intransitive.* To lay hold with the claws or (transferred) hands; to grasp or clutch (at, etc.); to scratch *at.*

Interestingly, *talon* is listed as an obsolete verb in *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/197331#eid19230552)* also, derived from the noun talon (the claws of a bird of prey):

> *Obsolete (transitive)* to tear with the talons; to claw.